# ImportError No module named requests_oauthlib error

Tags: python

using nohup python to run an .py file.
but face this error

```
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1, OAuth1Session
ImportError: No module named requests_oauthlib
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing module/library?

Comment: i had try pip install requests requests_oauthlib but still cant.( not sure if i am correct or nt)

Answer (score 4):

You should try the command `pip install requests_oauthlib`. It works for me.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: ver Python 3.7.3

Comment: What is the error showing when you write ```pip install requests_oauthlib```?

Comment: I think this answer should be `python -m pip install requests_oauthlib`, at least for Windows users.